Explicit $K$-basis of a Lie subalgebra
$\newcommand{\Kbar}{{\overline K}}
\newcommand{\Q}{{\mathbb Q}}
$I consider Example 5.7 of Sansuc's paper Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres of 1981.
Let $K=\Q$, $L=\Q(\sqrt{13},\sqrt{17})$. Let
$$ G=(R_{L/K} \operatorname{SL}_4)\,/ R^1_{L/K}\,\mu_4\,.$$
Here $R_{L/K}$ denotes the  Weil restriction of scalars, and
$$R^1_{L/K}\,\mu_4=\ker\bigl[\operatorname{Nm}_{L/K}\colon R_{L/K}\,\mu_4\to\mu_4\bigr].$$

Question: To test a computer program, I would like to embed $G\hookrightarrow \operatorname{GL}(W)$
for some vector space $W$ over $K$, and to compute (using a computer) a basis of the Lie subalgebra
$\operatorname{Lie}(G)\subset \mathfrak{gl}(W)$.
How can I do that?

Write $V=R_{L/K}L^4$, $H=R_{L/K}\operatorname{SL}(V)$.
Then $V$ is a $K$-irreducible representation of $H$,
and $V_\Kbar$ is a sum of four irreducible representations over $\Kbar$
$$V_\Kbar=V_{\phi_1}\oplus V_{\phi_2}\oplus V_{\phi_3}\oplus V_{\phi_4}$$
where $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_4$ are the different embeddings $L\hookrightarrow \Kbar$ over $K$.
Set
$$W=V^{\otimes 4}=V\otimes_K V \otimes_K V \otimes_K V.$$
Set
$$W_0=V_{\phi_1}\otimes V_{\phi_2}\otimes V_{\phi_3}\otimes V_{\phi_4}\subset W_\Kbar,
\quad\ W_1=\bigoplus_{\gamma\in\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)} {}^\gamma W_0.$$
Then the subspace  $W_0$ is defined over $L$,
the subspace $W_1\subset W_\Kbar$ is defined over $K$,
and $H$ acts on $W_1$ with kernel $R^1_{L/K}\,\mu_4$.
Alternatively, we consider the subspace
$$ W_2=\bigoplus_{(\phi_1',\dots,\phi_4')}V_{\phi_1'}\otimes\cdots\otimes V_{\phi_4'}\subset W_\Kbar $$
where $\phi_1',\dots,\phi_4'$ are four different embeddings
$L\hookrightarrow \Kbar$ over $K$ (in any order).
Again, $W_2$ is defined over $K$, and $H$ acts on $W_2$ with kernel $R^1_{L/K}\,\mu_4$.
We obtain embeddings of $G$ into $\operatorname{GL}(W_1)$ and $\operatorname{GL}(W_2)$.

Question. How can I compute in Magma a $K$-basis of $W_1$ or $W_2$  and a $K$-basis of $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$ in $\mathfrak{gl}(W_1)$ or in $\mathfrak{gl}(W_2)$, starting with a natural $K$-basis of $R_{L/K}V$?


Sansuc had two papers in 1981, only one of which I can access, but it doesn't have a §5—so I assumed you meant the other one, whose title looks promising but which I can't access, and edited it in.  I hope that was correct.

@LSpice: It was correct, thank you! I should have provided the reference myself!
